# Old screen does not disappear immediately

Tags: android, google-maps, tabactivity

I have tabActivity with two Activities.

1. ListActivity
2. FragmentActivity

In my listActivity I have field, that you clicked start new Activity

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {                 
    Obiekt item = (Obiekt)items.get(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, ActivityObjects.class);           
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_EVENT);

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
}
```

In the first case, I clicked item on list and go to second activity, when user clicked "Back button" activity disappear and listView is showing.

In the second case, I clicked "MapActivity" tab and go back to main tab "ListActivity". I clicked item on listView and go to another Activity, when user clicked "Back button" the screen is hanging about 2 second and listView is appear...

It is my xmp file:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

init mapActivity:

```
FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
myMapFragment  = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();
```

And how I add tabs to TabHost:

```
private void addMap(String labelId, Class<?> c) {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabs, getTabWidget(), false);
        TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(labelId);

        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
```

Android 2.3.3
I don't have this problem on android 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method of the back button to show the previous Activity and destroy the map fragment.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
  Log.d("MainActivity", "onKeyDown");
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
  {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
    ListActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    MapActivity.this.finish();                  
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think, that it is idea, but I lost data and memory, when creating new Activity

Comment: You could use SharedPreferences to save the data.